# Mediawiki Get Article Text from BeforePageDisplay Hook

Tags: php, hook, mediawiki

I am wondering if there is a way to get the article text from within the BeforePageDisplay hook on mediawiki?

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/BeforePageDisplay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the wikitext of the page, you should probably use a [parser hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:MediaWiki_hooks_included_in_Parser.php).

What do you need the text for? The [parser documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser.php) tells you more on the steps of the parsing, which will help you decide which hook to use: for instance, if you want the "complete" wikitext of the page, including the templates which the page calls, you need a hook which is run after `Parser::replaceVariables`.